# django redirecting blank url to named url

Tags: python, django, url

I have my url:

```
url(r'^home/', HomeQuestionView, name='home_question') ,
```

When I enter `localhost:8000/home` I get my homepage but what I want is when I just enter I get my homepage.
I mean I want to redirect to the above homepage url when user enters only my site like`www.xyz.com` not `www.xyz.com/home`

I dont want to configure in this way

```
url(r'^', HomeQuestionView, name='home_question') ,
```

Thanx in advance

Comment: Any particular reason behind why you don't want to use the r'^' configuration?

Comment: You don't want to do the exact thing that will make your site work the way you want?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use generic [RedirectView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.RedirectView):

```
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/home/')),
```

Answer (score 5):

I found this solution (long story short, you need to add views.py to your main project folder and make view which redirect your empty route to your url):

1. In your urls.py inside urlpatterns add this:

   ```
   urlpatterns = [
   ...
   path("", views.home, name="home"),
   ...
   ]
   ```
2. In main Django folder create views.py and import it in urls.py
   [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sqcX.png)
3. In views.py add this code:

   ```
   from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

   def home(request):
       return redirect("blog:index") # redirect to your page
   ```
4. Now every time your url will be empty like (localhost:8000) it will be redirected to (localhost:8000/your_adress). Also, you can use this not only with blank url, but anywhere you need this sort of redirection